# AdminConsole (Import DataSources) in SmartClient

Tags: sql-server, smartclient

I went to this link: /localhost:8080/tools/adminConsole.jsp and I selected a DataSource then I did "Import" therefore I lost all data I had on my database!

Have you an idea to retrieve my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no solution to this problem!
i must have a bakcup